# Java Socket Connection Failure

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, serversocket

I have a server code in Java which I run on my machine and my friend has a client code which runs on his machine. When he enters my IP so as to connect to my server and get the date, connection fails and nothing happens. Note that when I run server and client programs on my own machine and enter **localhost** as the address, connection is successful and I get the date message correctly. I'm looking for possible errors and problems causing this.

Server code in Java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9999);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                try {
                    PrintWriter out =
                            new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println(new Date().toString());
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client code in Java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n" +
                        "running the date service on port 9999:");
        Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 9999);
        BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String answer = input.readLine();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Firewall would be my first guess. (iptables/ufw/Windows Firewall)

Comment: @SeanBright

Well both of our firewalls are disabled :-/

Comment: @Sepehr-Please provide the stackTrace of the exception which occured!

Comment: Withing the same local network it should be fine, but If you are on different networks, e.g. you are trying to connect to server over the internet, it is highly likely that your home router is blocking the connection. A solution to this is to open your router settings and port forward 9999 to your local IP address

Answer (score 0):

Some routers might isolate computers in different networks. Try it with both computers on Wifi or both wired to the router. Are your IPs on the same network? Can you see your friend's computer on the network? There might also be some security configurations on your router.

Other than that and firewall issue (which you have disabled), the code looks like it should work fine.